# Get-S3Object(V2) does not seem to be able to handle a backslash in the key

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

Either I'm missing something obvious or I have stumbled upon an issue in using the `Get-S3Object(V2)` cmdlet.

It looks like keys containing a **backslash** are not supported.

Assuming a bucket containing

```
bucket/folder/testfile1
bucket/folder/\testfile2
```

I'm not able to retrieve `\testfile2` through `Get-S3Object(V2)`

###### AWS CLI behaves as expected

```
aws s3 --profile TEST ls s3://bucket/folder/
  => returns a listing
       testfile1
       \testfile2

aws s3 --profile TEST ls s3://bucket/folder/\testfile2
  => returns just the one key
       \testfile2
```

###### Get-S3ObjectV2 behaves as expected retrieving a list or testfile1

```
(Get-S3ObjectV2 -ProfileName 'TEST' -BucketName 'bucket' -Select '*' -Prefix 'folder/').S3Objects
  => Returns an S3Objects list containing
      bucket/folder/testfile1
      bucket/folder/\testfile2

(Get-S3ObjectV2 -ProfileName 'TEST' -BucketName 'bucket' -Select '*' -Prefix 'folder/testfile1').S3Objects
  => Returns an S3Objects list containing
      bucket/folder/testfile1

$null -ne (Get-S3ObjectV2 -ProfileName 'TEST' -BucketName 'bucket' -Key 'folder/testfile1') 
  => Returns True
```

###### but not when directly trying to get \testfile2

```
(Get-S3ObjectV2 -ProfileName 'TEST' -BucketName 'bucket' -Select '*' -Prefix 'folder/\testfile2').S3Objects
  => Returns an empty S3Objects list

$null -ne (Get-S3ObjectV2 -ProfileName 'TEST' -BucketName 'bucket' -Key 'folder/\testfile2')
  => Returns False
```

Comment: A backslash is in the [Characters to avoid](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html) in S3.  You'll likely need to escape these with some number of additional backslashes to escape it, i.e. 'folder/\\testfile2' or something similar.  Sorry, can't test it myself.

Comment: There's a quote from @stdunbar' link: "Avoid the following characters in a key name because of significant special handling for consistency across all applications."  Yep.  I've been using s3 for over 10 years and have a hard time justifying a backslash in the object key.  it's simple enough to remove at PutObject time.

Comment: @stdunbar
@erik258
I don't have much (if any) control on how the keys are written. All I can do is pass on the message. Escaping with double backslash, forward slash, ` all failed. If all else fails, I'm going to resort to AWS CLI io Get-S3Object. Not ideal but it is what it is. Thank you for your time.

Comment: "I don't have much (if any) control on how the keys are written." acknowledged.  You could deny writing objects with backslash in the keys with a bucket policy if you wanted.  But that assumes you control the bucket policy which you may not.  and that may not be what you want anyway.